# UIImageView is not showing image selected via UIIMagePickerController

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to select an image using the UIImagePickerController . I have the following code in which there is one IBOutlet of UIImageView.

After selecting the image in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo I get the image in memory but somehow it is not visible in the imageview. I did try to change a static image in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo for imageview but it didn't show the image either. The code is as below,

```
class SnapshotViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
      let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
            self.imageView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this is general problem that whatever image i am changing for this imageView in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is not working. If i change the imageView image in viewDidLoad then it works.
Can anyone please help as i need to show the image selected via photo library?

Comment: I would suggest to remove that unnecessary `dispatch_async` block, and try to set the image first, and only then dismiss the image picker.

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommended not to update UI controls from a background thread.  This can be the cause of strange behaviour and crashes which are sometimes very hard to identify.

Try to set the image on the main thread instead:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.imageView.image = image

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I tried it in the simulator and it works for me. Did you add <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key><string>descriptio‌​n here</string> to your info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code would solve your problem and make the picture from your photolibrary appear:

```
class PostViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {



    @IBOutlet var imageToPost: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func chooseAnImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        imagePicker.delegate = self

        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

            imageToPost.image = image


        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4, I tried various things but non of them work until I just add `@objc` annotation to `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` override method:

Pressenting `UIImagePickerController`:

```
@objc func handleSelectProfileImageView () {
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Extension to get media data (in this one I had to add `@objc`):

```
extension MyViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
        if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImage = image
            profileImage.image = image
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

About [`@objc` from doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html):

> Apply this attribute to any declaration that can be represented in
>   Objective-C—for example, nonnested classes, protocols, nongeneric
>   enumerations (constrained to integer raw-value types), properties and
>   methods (including getters and setters) of classes, protocols and
>   optional members of a protocol, initializers, and subscripts. The objc
>   attribute tells the compiler that a declaration is available to use in
>   Objective-C code.